# Capture the browser's back button in an MVC4 web application and execute a Controller's Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

We have developed an MVC4 Web Application. Due to the flow of pages (it is a reservation system) we need when the user pressed back button the page to be executed again ie reload data from database as it was called from first time.

May be a solution is to suggest how to Capture the browser's back button in an MVC4 web application and execute a Controller's Action

Kindly consider.
Any assistance is kindly appreciated.

Comment: When the user presses the back button, what is currently causing the page to not be loaded as if its the first time?

Comment: As a guess, is it that you've maintained state through the flow of pages (via session or database) and that when the user navigates (via the back button) to a previous page that you would like that state to be cleared?

Comment: Yes I would like that state to be cleared

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments it seems you are building up state over several pages (in a wizard style) and it is when navigating back to an earlier page that you would like the state to be cleared.

You would need to capture the page navigation logic on the server side and not rely on capturing back button events on the client side.

You should use the state you've captured to determine what should be displayed to the user and what should happen to the current state you have.

For example, imagine you have pages A, B, C, D which collect user information.  The user has entered information on pages A and B (which has been gathered in the session or the database perhaps) and is now on page C.  They then navigate back to page A (via the back button or by modifying the url directly).  At this point (in the controller for page A) you can determine from the current state that they have been to page B and therefore deduce that they must have navigated back.  You can therefore clear the state at this point or perform whatever logic is required.